# Windows Azure sdk 1.7, CloudTableClient missing GetTableReference function

Tags: windows, azure

banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why i'm missing this function.

the `CloudTableClient` is missing `GetTableReference`

```cs
var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(baseAddress, credentials) {Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30)};
tableClient.GetTableReference("table1");
```

doesn't show up in IntelliSense or in the Object Browser.

:(

Comment: I bet you're missing a usings.  Looks like an extension method.  Unfortunately, I don't know which namespace it's in either :P

Comment: i have resharper and its not saying anything. i don't even have the CloudTable class. I checked my references and i have Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll version 1.7.0.0

Comment: my assemblies for storage client say 1.7.0.0 i tried getting the latest sdk from github using nuget and it didn't upgrade to 1.7.1.0. wish i could just download the binaries rather than mess with github

Comment: seems to me like the github repo is messed up. i download it and it always downloads the old version (1.7.0)

Comment: Here's a longshot: are you trying to use this in a Client Framework profile or the full .NET Framework?

Comment: download as zip gets the latest though....

Comment: just checked, target framework .net framework 4

i think the github repo is messed up. if you download as zip. it downloads the latest. if you use github or nuget it downloads the old version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetTableRefenrece is part of Azure SDK **1.7.1** which is currently only available in [GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/sdk_1.7.1/microsoft-azure-api/StorageClient/CloudTableClient.cs). Only v. 1.7.0 is available via NuGET / WebPI Installer. This method returns an instance of [CloudTable](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/sdk_1.7.1/microsoft-azure-api/StorageClient/CloudTable.cs), which is also only part of Azure SDK **1.7.1**.

If you want to use it, they you have to download the source and build it on your own. There is nothing scary in downloading and building the official source of Azure SDK. I personally did it for a project, because I needed some functionality which does not exists in the older SDK.

Comment: their repo is messed up, when you download it using github it downloads 1.7.0. you have to download it as a zip, then open it and compile it.

Comment: Well, what is the mess? Just download the ZIP indeed (this is what I did and everything worked just fine).